# How to specify CppCodeProvider on command line of svcutil.exe?

Tags: c++-cli, codedom, svcutil.exe

I am trying to use svcutil to generate managed C++ code from XSD. The command line I am using is

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\xsd.exe" MyTest.xsd /classes /language:"Microsoft.VisualC.CppCodeProvider7, CppCodeProvider, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /namespace:MyTestApp

However, I get error message as follows

Error: Value 'microsoft.visualc.cppcodeprovider7, cppcodeprovider, version=10.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' for switch /language is invalid. There is no codedom provider defined for the language.

I know that I have CppCodeProvider installed as part of Visual Studio install. I have also tried /language:cpp to no avail. I was able to generate code in C# without any issue for the same XSD.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clearly stated in the MSDN Library article for svcutil.exe:

> `/language:<language>`
>
> Values: c#, cs, csharp, vb,
>   visualbasic, c++, cpp
>
> Default: csharp
>
> Short form: /l
>
> Note:   The switch only supports C++
>   for the code provider that ships with
>   Visual Studio 2005 SP1.

I think that came with the .NET 2.0 SDK back then.  Not otherwise a problem, the language hasn't changed since then.  Why not use csharp?  Being able to painlessly mix languages in .NET is one of its great assets.

Comment: We have a lot of code in unmanaged c++. We are in process of converting to managed (C# is the end goal). However, can't accept the cost of all or no change. Hence we need a way to make unmanaged calls.
Doing interop using marshalling is very costly as we have large data structures (composites) that need to go back and forth. Instead of that, I want to take control of marshalling selectively (into just the required data structures). This works like adapter design pattern.
Hence we need to use CIL.

Comment: Note: The switch only supports C++ for the code provider that ships with Visual Studio 2005 SP1.

Does that mean, I am forced to install Visual Studio 2005 SP1 to get the CPP code provider working?